# How to fade in div's linked to icons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fade in the divs that pop up when you roll over an icon at my Tumblr theme I'm building, roseannebarr.tumblr.com. I don't know how to :(

P.S: If you get a "We'll be back shortly" try again in a few minutes, thats Tumblr being stupid :(

Here is how Tumblr works; Tumblr uses their own "tags" to create posts entered from a user's dashboard. You can post a link, photo, text, chat, video, or an audio. I only entered a photo post below. Outer is the icon you hover over (it also uses "block") and tooltip is the actual content itself. The reason you view the source on my page but can't see this is because the tags ARE the content.

```
<div id="outer">
{block:Photo}
<img id="block" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/vYSlebvt2/photo.png">
<div id="tooltip">

{LinkOpenTag}<center><img id="photo" src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" /></center>    
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}

<img id="cover" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/pMHledd2y/cover.png">
<img id="cover" src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/pMHledd2y/cover.png">
</div>
{/block:Photo}
</div>
```

Comment: How are you currently getting the divs to appear and disappear? I have looked at the linked website in firebug but cannot figure out how it is happening.

Comment: I entered the HTML to a photo post above.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are currently using jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` methods to work with the those divs.

Instead jQuery has a `fadeIn()` and a `fadeOut()` function which do exactly as they sound, you can find the [docs for fadeIn here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).

It takes a time in milliseconds as the first argument and an optional function to be called when the animation has finished as the second:

```
$('div#whatever').fadeIn(200, function() {
    console.log('the fade has finished when this function is called');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myIconId').mouseover(function() {
    $('.mydivsClass').fadeIn(5000);
});
```

The one problem I see is that you have the same id on multiple elements on the page.  W3C states one ID but multiple classes.  You may have to do some refactoring to get the above to work.  You need some way to match your icons up with an image, and typically that is what the id tags would do.

Comment: Ya I guess but ugh it took me so long to just get it to work and in a simple way :( That didn't work because the thing that fades in is an id.

Comment: Try Marcus's answer, replace your show() with fadeIn().  You must have done something to get the different photos to show, so perhaps you can build upon that.  Posting the code might help one of us determine what you've done so we can offer a more targeted answer.

Comment: I tried both and neither worked. I would assume I would use that code and replace div#whatever with div#tooltip since that is the div that is going to fade in.

Comment: Then please post the code you used to show the photos when mouseover of the items.  I'm sure there is a solution if you can help narrow the scope.

Comment: Ok, I also put a detailed explanation on how Tumblr works incase you didn't know.

Comment: This is an ugly solution, but you could try using CSS to keep your photos hidden and then use mouseover attributes in your HTML to invoke the show and fadeIn calls.  Jquery has a "find" method that you can use to look for children elements so it won't get confused by the fact that you have N elements with the same id.

Comment: I want the divs called "tooltip" to fade in. I don't want the icons to fade in. I want the entire div's that pop up to fade in when they "pop up"